# Xamarin.Forms App - Detect "Close App / Wait" Popup Message

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Android app written in Xamarin.Forms.

I have been informed by our users that occasionally on certain screens, the app gets really slow and they are presented with a popup message that gives the options: "Close App" / "Wait".

I can sort of sort replicate the issue, so I am currently in the process of providing a fix and therefore I don't need help with this part.

I was wondering however, if it was possible to somehow detect that the app is slowing down or to at least detect when this popup message appears?  Basically I am trying to understand how big of a problem this is and how many users experience the issue, so if possible I would like to send a log report to our servers when this popup appears.

Comment: Are you running a huge block of code that is actually using the MainThread somewhere? Please add more info or a specific piece of code that is causing this issue may be

Comment: I'm not running a huge block of code on the MainThread - basically, I have a screen that contains multiple controls (many labels, images etc.) and then a ListView.  The user will scan a barcode which calls a handler that performs several checks (such as validation) and then adds the barcode to the ListView.

Comment: When scanning hundreds of barcodes in quick succession, you can see the screen responsiveness slowing down, and then eventually you get the "Close app / Wait" popup.  The popup comes from our Scanner Engine due to the MainThread being slow, so I'm currently improving the way the screen is designed to speed up the UI but was hoping that there is a way to detect when the popup is displayed so that I can verify that my changes have fixed the issue but also so that I can see how big of a problem this issue is with our LIVE users.

Comment: Just to clarify - the "Close app / Wait" popup is an Android popup due to the app being slow and not something that my app directly displays.

Comment: I know how Android ANR works, That is why I asked you this in the first place! I would suggest you read this blog of mine https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/techniques-for-improving-performance-in-a-xamarin-forms-application-b439f2f04156

Comment: Thanks for the link - I already have that document though and that's what I'm using to help me improve the performance of my screen.  What I want to be able to  do though, is somehow detect that the "Close app / Wait" popup has been displayed so that I can sure that the improvements have actually fixed the issue.  I appreciate that this may not be possible and is probably a big ask but thought that if it was possible then it could be useful.

Comment: Isn't your blog post the same as this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance